Dynamics-generated appointment invites: how to hide email addresses
IN Dynamics 365 When Saving an Appointment for >1 Required person, Microsoft sends a meeting invite to all - but everyone sees everyone else's email address.  What about data privacy?!  This is built into D365, there are no Settings for it.  Is there any way to hide the email addresses?
Looked at Exchange, D365 for Outlook, Dynamics itself of course...can't find a way.  Most common Google result is Outlook for Web's Hide Attendee List but that's not relevant, this is coming from D365.
